# Django Rest Framework / AngularJS - Users do not get redirected anywhere after logging in, even though I have set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

According to this link: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-login-to-the-browsable-api

I need to add the following code to my URLs.py:

```
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls',
                               namespace='rest_framework')),
```

When I added this, users can log in by going to the "api-auth" URL and using the default DjangoRestFramework login interface. After a successful login, users are directed to "/test" because I have the following code in my settings.py:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/test'
```

I wanted a way for users to be able to log-in using my own custom interface but by using DjangoRestFramework's built-in code for logging users in, so I created my own template. The login form in the template sends a post request to

```
api-auth/login/
```

and sends the user object (which consists of a username and password in JS) along with the POST request. No errors are returned, so I'm assuming the login is successful. However, it does not redirect to any URL (I was expecting it to redirect to "/test").

Any idea why it does not redirect anywhere, and how I can make it redirect to "/test"?

Edit: I am also using AngularJS on the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` is basically from `django.contrib.auth` so I wouldn't except other auth backends to use it, at least not necessarily/automatically

Also if you're logging through REST say from an AngularJS, even if after the REST API login is successful and returns a *redirect response*, there is no guarantee that the AngularJS app will navigate to that page because the login REST API was hit using an XHR request (from `$http` or `$resource` etc)

I'm using a slightly different REST auth lib than you, called `django-rest-auth` (not the BrowsableAPI that comes with DRF), I'm authenticating from AngularJS, and after the call is done with success, I simply navigate the app to a new URL

```
djangoAuth.login(username, password).then(function(){
    // make angularJS navigate to new page when login is successful
    // $location.path(...) or some other way
});
```

Bottom line is, since you have an auth API, you can make a small AngularJS page, with login form, then when login is successful redirect with AngularJS

**Worth a look**

I'm using these two libs that are meant to be used together, they offer REST auth over DRF, and optional a AngularJS lib to help with the frontend

- https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth
- https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth

Comment: Okay thanks. After reading your post, the way I am thinking about doing it is to send a POST request to the backend, and if the request is sucessful, redirect like so: self.loginUser = function() {
            $http.post("/custom-api-auth/login", self.loginuser)
            .then(function(response) {
                // If the login is successful. redirect to a path using $location.path(...);
            }, function(response) {
                // otherwise if there is an error, handle the error here
           }); }; Would this also be a valid and okay way of doing it?